# Amazon SWF - List Workflow Execution IDs of Pending Activity Tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I can use the `CountPendingActivityTasks` method to list how many workflow executions are in the queue of a particular activity. Is there anyway to list the workflow execution IDs of those executions waiting in the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible. Note that *CountPendingActivityTasks* returns "an approximation and is not guaranteed to be exact".

Do you need it for monitoring/troubleshooting or it is a business requirement?

Comment: Monitoring - that was what I assumed after not finding a method in the references.  I was eventually able to implement another methodology using our internal task tracking system to get the info I wanted.